# Route53 only for wildcard subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-route53

We recently moved our web application to AWS. One thing that is still managed by our old hoster is DNS.

```
OLD HOSTER
example.com.    NS     <Old hoster's name server> 
example.com.    A      <ElasticIP on EC2 instance>
*.example.com.  CNAME  example.com.
...
```

I'm now trying to setup and play around with Route53 and use it for name resolution of our EC2 instances.

```
ROUTE53
web-01.aws.example.com.  CNAME  ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com.
web-02.aws.example.com.  CNAME  ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com.
...
```

Now my question: Is it possible to forward DNS queries for *.aws.example.com to Route53 (ns-xxxx.awsdns-59.co.uk.)? What kind of record would I have to add?

---

**Update**

Now I've got the following NS records:

```
OLD HOSTER: Zone example.com.
example.com.      NS     <Old hoster's name server> 
example.com.      A      <ElasticIP on EC2 instance>
*.example.com.    CNAME  example.com.
...

OLD HOSTER: Zone aws.example.com.
aws.example.com.  NS     ns-1324.awsdns-37.org.
aws.example.com.  NS     ns-384.awsdns-48.com.
aws.example.com.  NS     ns-1754.awsdns-27.co.uk.
aws.example.com.  NS     ns-590.awsdns-09.net.

ROUTE53: Zone aws.example.com.
aws.example.com.         NS     ns-1324.awsdns-37.org.
aws.example.com.         NS     ns-384.awsdns-48.com.
aws.example.com.         NS     ns-1754.awsdns-27.co.uk.
aws.example.com.         NS     ns-590.awsdns-09.net.
web-01.aws.example.com.  CNAME  ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com.
web-02.aws.example.com.  CNAME  ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com.
...
```

However, when I'm doing a nslookup for web-01.aws.example.com I get the A record (ElasticIP) from the old server. When I do a lookup for the host on ns-1324.awsdns-37.org I do get the CNAME record. So the problem is somewhere with the old DNS service I'd guess.

Do I need to add something to the example.com zone (not the aws.example.com zone) on AWS?

TTLs are at 3600, so that should not be the problem.

Many thanks for any additional help.

---

**Resolved**

This is my final setup.

```
OLD HOSTER: Zone example.com.
example.com.      NS     <Old hoster's name server>
aws.example.com.  NS     ns-1324.awsdns-37.org.
aws.example.com.  NS     ns-384.awsdns-48.com.
aws.example.com.  NS     ns-1754.awsdns-27.co.uk.
aws.example.com.  NS     ns-590.awsdns-09.net.
example.com.      A      <ElasticIP on EC2 instance>
*.example.com.    CNAME  example.com.
...

ROUTE53: Zone aws.example.com.
aws.example.com.         NS     ns-1324.awsdns-37.org.
aws.example.com.         NS     ns-384.awsdns-48.com.
aws.example.com.         NS     ns-1754.awsdns-27.co.uk.
aws.example.com.         NS     ns-590.awsdns-09.net.
web-01.aws.example.com.  CNAME  ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com.
web-02.aws.example.com.  CNAME  ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com.
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would add appropriate NS records for `aws.example.com` pointing to Route53's name servers. For example:

```
aws.example.com. IN NS ns-2012.awsdns-59.co.uk.
aws.example.com. IN NS ns-650.awsdns-14.com.
aws.example.com. IN NS ns-102-awsdns-45.org.
```

Comment: David's answer is correct. But to clarify, you need to add NS records on both the old DNS server (to get DNS transferred to Route 53) and on Route 53 itself (to keep it pointed there after the transfer).

Route 53 will provide these three NS hosts for you when you create the entry there. It will take time for this migration to take effect, depending on your timeout settings at your old DNS provider.

Comment: Yes, quite correct. The `example.com` zone on your server needs these `aws.example.com` entries. And Route 53 needs an `aws.example.com` zone that also contains these NS entries as well as whatever else you want it to do.

Comment: Hi! I've updated the question and any additional help would be appreciated. Thx. :)

Comment: Make sure there's no `aws.example.com` zone on the old server.